# Why v8::JSON::Parse from v8 much slower than NodeJS JSON::parse?

Tags: javascript, c++, json, node.js, v8

I know that NodeJS built on top of V8. That's why it looks so strange, when my c++ wrapper around v8 parses json file (2 Mb) in 394 seconds and NodeJS scripts parses the same json file in 167 seconds.

In C++ I call parse json in this way

`v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> jsonData = v8::JSON::Parse(isolate, v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, data));`

and in NodeJS `JSON.parse(data)`.

Also when I call `v8::JSON::Parse` in a loop like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  v8::JSON::Parse(isolate, v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, data));
}
```

it eats all my memory and OOM killer kills my app. Why it works in this way ? Maybe this function contains mem leaks or I need to free something.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I only bet that in the pure v8 use, the json returned from 'JSON::parse' is destroyed right away while in node.js, it garbage collected either asynchronously, either in outside the loop. Try to chunk the returned jsons in a resrved vector  and see if the performance goes up.

Comment: Thx for your answer. "Try to chunk the returned jsons in a resrved vector and see if the performance goes up." I don't exactly understand what do you mean by that.

Comment: It looks like all way around.
In c++ case we have huge memory consumption without free. But in a NodeJS case memory frees constantly.
You maybe right about GC and when it works, but it look like in my case I need to call GC in C++ manually to free json data.

Comment: If I add v8::HandleScope scope(isolate); inside look it will work just fine.

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {

    v8::HandleScope scope(isolate);

    v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> jsonData = v8::JSON::Parse(context, v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, data));

  }

Comment: it obviously cannot garbage collect inside the loop, as the handlecontext isn't inside the loop

Comment: Okay, but why the NodeJS so much faster ? Is it the problem with GC ?